# How do I make my if statement work in my game?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am making a color sequence game. The player will be given four random colors and will have to click each block to get them in the correct color sequence. Everything works besides the winning if statement. For testing purposes, I used an alert that says "yay" when the player wins. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I've tried multiple things to make this work. My if statement is at the bottom of the code.

Javascript:

```
<script>
var colors;
var o;
var t;
var th;
var f;
var oa;
var ta;
var tha;
var fa;
function sequence(){
oa = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
ta = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
tha = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
fa = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
document.getElementById('sequence').innerHTML = "1:" + oa + " 2:" + ta + " 3:" + tha + " 4:" + fa;
};
window.onload = function(){
randomize();
sequence();
};
function randomize(){
colors = ['#ff0000','#ff5500','#ffff00','#00ff00','#0000ff','#8c00ff'];
o = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
t = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
th = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
f = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
one = document.getElementById('one').style.background = o;
two = document.getElementById('two').style.background = t;
three = document.getElementById('three').style.background = th;
four = document.getElementById('four').style.background = f;
}
function changeOne(){
o = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
document.getElementById('one').style.background = o;
}
function changeTwo(){
t = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
document.getElementById('two').style.background = t;
}
function changeThree(){
th = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
document.getElementById('three').style.background = th;
}
function changeFour(){
f = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
document.getElementById('four').style.background = f;
}
//this is the part I need help with
if(o==oa && t==ta && th==tha && f==fa){
alert("yay!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. How exactly does the `if` statement not work?

Comment: the if statement is run exactly once, before the window.onload function is even executed - perhaps that answers your question ... p.s. learn to format code

Comment: It doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try to create a function for your if statement and call it like you are calling the other functions

Comment: That didn't work either...

Comment: Thank you, but do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

maybe because the array of colors you chose consists of colors so similar to each other. anyway I changed your code and add an html. look if it is what you looking for:

```js
var colors;
var o;
var t;
var th;
var f;
var oa;
var ta;
var tha;
var fa;
function sequence(){
oa = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
ta = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
tha = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
fa = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
var oaDiv = document.createElement("div");
oaDiv.style.backgroundColor=oa;
var taDiv = document.createElement("div");
taDiv.style.backgroundColor=ta;
var thaDiv = document.createElement("div");
thaDiv.style.backgroundColor=tha;
var faDiv = document.createElement("div");
faDiv.style.backgroundColor=fa;
oaDiv.classList.add("colorDiv1");
taDiv.classList.add("colorDiv1");
thaDiv.classList.add("colorDiv1");
faDiv.classList.add("colorDiv1");
document.getElementById('sequence').appendChild(oaDiv);
document.getElementById('sequence').appendChild(taDiv);
document.getElementById('sequence').appendChild(thaDiv);
document.getElementById('sequence').appendChild( faDiv);

//document.getElementById('sequence').innerHTML = "1:" + oa + " 2:" + ta + " 3:" + tha + " 4:" + fa;
};
window.onload = function(){
randomize();
sequence();
};
function randomize(){
colors = ['#ff0000','#d500ff','#ffff00','#00ff00','#0000ff','#ff00f3'];
o = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
t = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
th = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
f = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
document.getElementById('one').style.backgroundColor  = o;
document.getElementById('two').style.backgroundColor  = t;
document.getElementById('three').style.backgroundColor  = th;
document.getElementById('four').style.backgroundColor  = f;
}
document.getElementById('one').addEventListener("click",function (){
o = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
document.getElementById('one').style.backgroundColor  = o;
ResultTest();
});
document.getElementById('two').addEventListener("click",function(){
t = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
document.getElementById('two').style.backgroundColor  = t;
ResultTest();
});
document.getElementById('three').addEventListener("click",function (){
th = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
document.getElementById('three').style.backgroundColor  = th;
ResultTest();
});
document.getElementById('four').addEventListener("click",function (){
f = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(colors.length))];
document.getElementById('four').style.backgroundColor  = f;
ResultTest();
});
//this is the part I need help with
 function ResultTest(){
  
 if(  o===oa && t===ta && th===tha && f===fa){
  console.log("yay");
   alert("yay!");  
 }
 
}
```

```css
.seq{
   position:absolute;
   
  }
  .seq2{
   position:relative;
   margin-top:70px;
   
  }
  .colorDiv1{
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  }
  .colorDiv{
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Section 2: JavaScript Language Basics</title>
  <style>
  
  
  </style>
    </head>

    <body>        
  <div id ="sequence" class="seq"></div>
<br/>
  <div class="seq2">  
  
  
  <div id ="one" class = "colorDiv "></div>
  <div id ="two" class = "colorDiv"></div>
  <div id ="three" class = "colorDiv"></div>
  <div id ="four" class = "colorDiv"></div>
  </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

```js
I hope It helps
```

Comment: Hey @rez shahr, this is a good starting point, but maybe you can turn it into a proper SO snippet, then you and the OP can play around with it to further improve it? https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/